# How to order a two-way table in R

Tags: r

I created a table in R using the following command:

```
ExamSex<-table(Exam, Sex)
```

I want to now sort the table by values of Exam, and create a new table with sorted values. How can I do that?

Comment: give us some data to work on, and so, examples and so what you have done so far.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please provide us a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Perhaps `ExamSex[order(rownames(ExamSex)), ]`? By default, I would expect the values of "Exam" to end up as your `rownames`, but as others have suggested, show some sample data, what output you expect, and what you've tried.

Comment: Hey Ananda - thanks a ton... so i was missing the "," in subsetting ExamSex and it kept returning values from the table but did not present the table as normal. Learning R a bit on the fly so my fundamentals are a bit challenged. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2826690, OK. I've posted it as an answer for the benefit of others. In the future, try to post a reproducible example so others aren't guessing at what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `table` is essentially a `matrix`, so you can work with it in much the same way you would work with a matrix.

When you use `table` on two items, the `rownames` become the unique values of the first item and the `colnames` become the unique values of the second item.

Here's an example:

```
out <- table(state.division, state.region)
out
#                     state.region
# state.division       Northeast South North Central West
#   New England                6     0             0    0
#   Middle Atlantic            3     0             0    0
#   South Atlantic             0     8             0    0
#   East South Central         0     4             0    0
#   West South Central         0     4             0    0
#   East North Central         0     0             5    0
#   West North Central         0     0             7    0
#   Mountain                   0     0             0    8
#   Pacific                    0     0             0    5
unique(state.division)
# [1] East South Central Pacific            Mountain           West South Central
# [5] New England        South Atlantic     East North Central West North Central
# [9] Middle Atlantic   
# 9 Levels: New England Middle Atlantic South Atlantic ... Pacific
unique(state.region)
# [1] South         West          Northeast     North Central
# Levels: Northeast South North Central West
```

Thus, if we wanted to order by the first value, we would need to order by the `rownames` of your table:

```
out[order(rownames(out)), ]
#                     state.region
# state.division       Northeast South North Central West
#   East North Central         0     0             5    0
#   East South Central         0     4             0    0
#   Middle Atlantic            3     0             0    0
#   Mountain                   0     0             0    8
#   New England                6     0             0    0
#   Pacific                    0     0             0    5
#   South Atlantic             0     8             0    0
#   West North Central         0     0             7    0
#   West South Central         0     4             0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Some users may want to sort the rows by decreasing total row frequencies and columns by decreasing total column frequencies. This would be the equivalent of setting `order=freq` when creating a two-way table in SAS using `proc freq`. This can be done in R as follows:

```
ExamSex <- table(Exam, Sex)
ExamSex <- ExamSex[order(rowSums(ExamSex), decreasing = TRUE), ]
ExamSex <- ExamSex[, order(colSums(ExamSex), decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Or, in a more compact functional form with pipe operator (`magrittr` package required),

```
ordered_twoway <- function(x, y) {
 table(unname(x), unname(y)) %>%
     `[`(order(rowSums(.), decreasing = TRUE), ) %>%
     `[`(, order(colSums(.), decreasing = TRUE))
}

ordered_twoway(Exam, Sex)
```